# I'm trying to find the difference between two arrays but my code isn't working for 0s any advice?

Tags: javascript, arrays

here is my code:

```
function arrayDiff(a, b) {  
  let newArr = a.concat(b);

  let singleVals = newArr.filter(num =>{
    if(!a.includes(num) || !b.includes(num))
      return num;
  })
  
  return singleVals;
}
```

an example of a result I'm looking for would be

```
a = [-16,12,5,8]
b = [12,5,8]

result = [-16]
```

That test would work with my code at the moment, however with something like this

```
a = [-16,6,19,0,9]
b = [9,-16,6]

my result = [19] when it should be [19,0]
```

I assume it has something to do with 0 counted as false or something like that. But an explanation would help.

Thanks

Comment: What about duplicates? `[0, 0]` and `[0]`, result: `[0]` or `[]`?

Comment: for [0,0] and [0] the result is []

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a number in filter but filter likes to get a boolean.
So it evaluates all the **values !== 0 to true** and evaluate **zero to false** like you assumed.

- When you return now for example 19 then it evaluates to true and it will be in your singleVals Array.
- But if you return 0 it evaluates to false and it won't be in your singleVals Array

Here a list of the 6 falsey values if you convert any of those to a boolean it will return false

```
false
undefined
null
NaN
0
"" (empty string)
```

You have to return a boolean instead of a number in your filter function.

```js
function arrayDiff(a, b) {
let newArr = a.concat(b);

let singleVals = newArr.filter( num =>{
// it is not including the number  
if(!a.includes(num) || !b.includes(num)){
     return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
})
  return singleVals
}

console.log(arrayDiff([3,2,1,0], [3,2,1,4,5])); // expected 0, 4, 5 
console.log(arrayDiff([-16,6,19,0,9],[9,-16,6])); // expected 9, 19
```

More Informations

https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/19-2-ways-to-convert-to-boolean/

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it has to do with zeroes being falsy. `Array.prototype.filter` expects a function that returns a boolean, not a number.

```js
function arrayDiff(a, b) {
  let newArr = a.concat(b);
  let singleVals = newArr.filter(num => {
    let isMissing = !a.includes(num) || !b.includes(num)
    return isMissing
  })
  return singleVals
}

console.log(arrayDiff([3,4,2,0],[1,2,3,4])); // expected 0, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient alternative is to use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) in place of the `newArr = a.concat(b)`, since `Set` never contains duplicates.

```js
function arrayDiff(a, b) {
  const uniques = new Set([...a, ...b]);
  return Array.from(uniques.values())
    .filter(
      val => !a.includes(val) || !b.includes(val)
    );
}

const a = [-16, 6, 19, 0, 9],
  b = [9, -16, 6];

const singleVals = arrayDiff(a, b);

console.log('singleVals:', JSON.stringify(singleVals));
```

Answer (score 0):

## If running time matters...

You didn't ask about this directly, but a number of these solutions contain nested loops, which will blow up on you for larger input arrays.  So, in case you want a suggestion that is more efficient in terms of time, I've added this one.

Nested loops are not desirable from an algorithmic efficiency perspective.  If `a` has 10 items, and `b` has 8 items, and you're looping over every "b" for every "a", your running time will grow as the product of the size of those two arrays, quickly becoming very slow (`O(n*m)`).  You're doing `8*10 = 80` steps to process 18 values.  Imagine if it were 100 * 100, or 1000 * 1000...

Here's a solution that returns a result without nested loops, at the cost of creating two sets and an extra array for the results.  From what I can see this is no more space than any of the other suggestions would take, and less time:

```js
const a = [-16, 6, 19, 0, 9]
const b = [9, -16, 6]

function diff(a, b) {
  // Set creation is O(n) time and space, where n is the length of array a
  const aUniques = new Set(a)
  // Set creation is O(m) time and space, where m is the length of array b
  const bUniques = new Set(b)

  // Final array is at worst space O(n + m), but usually much less
  const allUniques = []

  // A single loop, O(n) time
  aUniques.forEach(value => {
    // Set lookups are very fast, O(1).
    if (!bUniques.has(value)){
      allUniques.push(value)
    }
  })
  
   // A single loop, O(m) time
   bUniques.forEach(value => {
    if (!aUniques.has(value)){
      allUniques.push(value)
    }
  })
   
  // Final runtime is O(n) + O(m) + O(n) + O(m), or O(2n +2m)
  // This grows as O(n+m), which time-wise is much better than O(n*m).
  return allUniques
}

console.log(diff(a, b))
```

Does this matter for small input arrays?  No.  But it's good to understand the implications of different approaches.

A nice, short article on "big O" notation, if it helps: https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/